# Is there an easy way to set up ASP.NET Membership tables in a custom Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-structures, asp.net-membership

**ASP.NET Membership** is just great as there are a ton of functionality right there to be used, and we don't need to change nothing at all.

We can even create our own Provider based on Membership database, and that give us infinite possibilities, like as I don't like the Question/Answer I just use an email that is sent with a reset link.

But this is all done with **SQLEXPRESS** `.mdf` file and I wanted to use my own Database for this so I can use SQL Server Enterprise as we have in the Office and not the Express Edition.

> How can I easily use the ASP.NET Membership tables in my own Database?

I rememebered some years ago that we needed to use `aspnet_reg` (something) to create the correct tables, but I can't find that info anymore.

I also tried to use other Membership Providers, namely `Altairis.Web.Security` from [CodePlex](http://altairiswebsecurity.codeplex.com) and saw the Chris Pels [Video on creating a new Membership Provider](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

On `Altairis` solution, the Model is not complete and lack several points such as Several Applications as it's made to be used with only one, and Chris Pels contains to much Store Procedures that I need to create by hand.

I'm for given Chris code a go but I just wanted to know if there would be available something easier.

All this is to be integrated in ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Do it by running `aspnet_regsql.exe`: Just open "Start Menu>All Programs>Microsoft Visual Studio 2010>Visual Studio Tools>Visual Studio Command Prompt(2010)" and then type `aspnet_regsql`. A wizard appears and let you select your desired database.
2. Do it via API: Use `System.Web.Management.SqlServices` class and its `Install` and `Uninstall` methods. This will programmatically install/uninstall database artifacts.
3. Do it manually: Go to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` or something like. You will find 9 `.sql` files that begins with Install and 9 `.sql` files that begins with uninstall. You can run them manually in your database to create needed tables/store procedures/etc. But consider changing database name in sql scripts. Default db name is `aspnetdb`.

Answer (score 2):

It's aspnet_regsql

Under the following path:
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql

Comment: the tag `asp.net-mvc-2` inherits from .NET 3.5 SP1+ :)

Comment: could also be under the Framework64 folder if you're on a x64 OS

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up the Visual Studio Command Prompt, navigate to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\aspnet_regsql.exe . Some example are located in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Example: **aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A mr** - installs the database elements for membership and role management on the local computer running SQL Server using Windows authentication.