# using forms authentication with my own tables

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, forms-authentication

I have a small db, nothing fancy just 5 tables. I would like to use forms authentication but it creates its own db to do its stuff. I don't need anything fancy, and I certainly don't need the added infrastructure, but I'd like the security forms authentication provides. I have a person table, with a login and password field. how can I make it so forms uses these fields and returns my users id? is this even possible with forms? if not, how can I make it so forms creates it's infrastructure on my db so I can merge my tables with the ones forms needs to work?

I know this is probably quite simple but I haven't found anything on the net after hours of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own tables then you're going to have to [implement your own MembershipProvider](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/780/creating-a-custom-membership-provider/). This allows you to use your own tables and stored procedures, but still hook into the forms auth structure.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I'm not sure why the answers here imply that Forms Authentication somehow **must** be used with ASP.Net Membership or the ASP.Net infrastructure for it (providers, etc).

You can certainly use Forms Authentication **without** any of them and use your existing user tables (that have nothing to do with ASP.Net Membership or any provider for that matter).

This is taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx):

```
<script runat="server">
  void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if ((UserEmail.Text == "jchen@contoso.com") && 
        (UserPass.Text == "37Yj*99Ps"))
      {
          FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage 
             (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
      }
    else
      {
          Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
      }
  }
</script>
```

While the above is (over) simplified, you can see where you can replace the code with db lookup queries....

Update: modified link (corrected it to point to MSDN)

Comment: hmmmm that looks interesting. certainly more attractive than writing a whole provider. I'll take a look at it. thanks!

Comment: No problem - while writing a provider and/or overriding methods in existing providers is certainly possible, just wanted to clarify that **Forms Authentication** is **not** dependent on them. It can be "bolted on" to your (pre)existing user/pwd scheme/database tables, etc. - using Forms Authentication doesn't mean you have to "replace" your existing infrastructure - you *can* if you want to, but its *not necessary*...

Answer (score -1):

The tool you're looking for is called aspnet_regsql: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx

And here's a more comprehensive answer than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030700/44372